# Using underscore's _.extend(...) without overriding some of the destination's members

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like to be able to use underscore's `extend` function and implement a specific case. By default, `extend` overrides any existing member of the destination with that of the source. My problem with this is that I want to keep the initialize method of both the destination and the source intact, so what I did was roughly:

```
addComponent: function(comp, init) {
   var iF;
   if (comp.initialize) {
       iF = comp.initialize;
       delete comp["initialize"];
   }

   _.extend(this,comp);

   if (iF) {
       comp.initialize = iF;
       comp.initialize.call(this,init);
   }

   return this;
}
```

Is this the proper way to do it - by detaching and reattaching? I mean, I want to keep underscore intact, and I don't want to extend it with any methods, because this is a very specific case. Do you spot any potential

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just a quick idea, `_.extend` can accept multiple sources:

```
_.extend( this, comp, { initialize:this.initialize });
```

Answer (score 17):

I am really late to the party, but [`_.defaults`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) is what you were looking for.

Comment: _.defaults only can do it for one level.  if something like: {a:{b:"XYZ"}} and {a:{c:"TTT" }}  then it won't work.  Is there a multi-level defaults?